# How to automate the executions of the same program in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, pycharm

I have a bunch of datasets that need to be tested by using always the same .py program.

I want to automate all the testing process, so that after that one dataset has been tested and evaluated, automatically the program .py starts by testing (and evaluating) the next one.

I'm using the PyCharm IDE and I tried by adding configuration files that execute the same .py program but that take in input different file paths.

I was wondering whether there is a tool (or a command sequence to be followed in the command line) that let me automate the process of automatic testing or that let me call all the configurations created one after the other.

I'm talking about 6-8 hours per configuration, and currently I've 4 configurations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just write a loop that will call your test script with each of the configuration files?

Comment: Yeah.. I think it's the only affordable solution.. I mean, we're talking of a (not-so) huge dataset, so, I'll follow your suggestion! Thank you!